# How to auto-send a message in Google Groups (e.g., on request to join)?

Tags: google-groups

I help manage a large Google group (consumer, not business). We migrated the group from Yahoo Groups about a month ago.

We have a screening process for new members. When someone asks to join, we want them to automatically get a short questionnaire. If they pass the screening process, we confirm them. Otherwise, we don't.

In Yahoo groups, we could send automatic messages on various events, such as Request to Join. I cannot find a parallel function in Google Groups.

Does anyone know of a way to do this? The solution could be some tool that checks periodically for new Join Requests or something that extracts the email address from the email the owners get or ... (something else).

Answer (score 1):

When someone asks to join, by visiting the group /join URL, 
you already have the option of requiring them to answer a question 
that you setup in Permissions / Basic Permissions.

Comment: True - but that only works on the web form, not for someone sending an email request to join. Also, it is limited to 200 characters - not enough for us...  Thanks, Yosh

Comment: In the join request web form, or even in the group 'welcome message' or 'Group description' , you could include  a link to a Google Form, saying that it's necessary to fill and submit the form before requesting to join.

Comment: thanks - that's a good idea to get around the 200-char limit. Of course, I still have the problem that someone who sends a subscribe request by email will not see that info. Only someone who finds us in the directory or via the join URL would see it. Since many people try to join via email (having heard of us by word-of-mouth), I still need a solution for that path. But thanks for the form idea - I'll probably implement that to handle the web-based joins. If you have any other ideas, I'll be happy to hear.